# CS50 Pset3 Plurality - Unable to display the second candidate as winner

Tags: cs50

The code works fine even when it is a tie. E.g. Candidates A, B, C, if A gets two votes and B gets two votes, it will print A and B.

If C gets most votes, it will also print C. But when B gets most votes, it just keep printing A. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

Check50 messages as below:

:) print_winner identifies Alice as winner of election

**:( print_winner identifies Bob as winner of election**

**Cause
print_winner function did not print winner of election**

:) print_winner identifies Charlie as winner of election

:) print_winner prints multiple winners in case of tie

:) print_winner prints all names when all candidates are tied

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Max number of candidates
#define MAX 9

// Candidates have name and vote count
typedef struct
{
    string name;
    int votes;
}
candidate;

// Array of candidates
candidate candidates[MAX];

// Number of candidates
int candidate_count;

// Function prototypes
bool vote(string name);
void print_winner(void);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // Check for invalid usage
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: plurality [candidate ...]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Populate array of candidates
    candidate_count = argc - 1;
    if (candidate_count > MAX)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of candidates is %i\n", MAX);
        return 2;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        candidates[i].name = argv[i + 1];
        candidates[i].votes = 0;
    }

    int voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");

    // Loop over all voters
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        string name = get_string("Vote: ");

        // Check for invalid vote
        if (!vote(name))
        {
            printf("Invalid vote.\n");
        }
    }

    // Display winner of election
    print_winner();
}

// Update vote totals given a new vote
bool vote(string name)
{
    for(int a = 0; a < candidate_count; a++)
    {
        if(strcmp(name, candidates[a].name) == 0)
        {
            candidates[a].votes++;
            printf("%i\n", candidates[a].votes);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Print the winner (or winners) of the election
void print_winner(void)
{
    int winner_votes;
    for(int a = 1; a < candidate_count; a++)
    {
        if(candidates[a].votes <= candidates[0].votes)
        {
            winner_votes = candidates[0].votes;
        }
        else
        {
            winner_votes = candidates[a].votes;
        }
    }
    for (int b = 0; b < candidate_count; b++)
    {
        if(candidates[b].votes == winner_votes)
        {
            printf("%s\n", candidates[b].name);
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This `if(candidates[a].votes <= candidates[0].votes)` is a problem in an election where Alice gets 1 vote, Bob gets 2 votes and Charlie gets 1 vote. `winner_votes` will be set to 1 when a = 2. That comparison cannot be based on any particular candidates votes (ie `candidates[0]`), but rather on the "current" `winner_votes`.